# tcolorbox and tikzpicture not working breakable(Continued on the next page)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I have tried to create a table chart that simulates a notebook, but I cannot make it continue on the next page

[image: preview]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[showframe=true, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}%
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [signal,draw,signal to=nowhere,text=white,fill=blue!50, signal from=east] at (8,24.3) {Write book};
    \draw[help lines,step=0.5cm]            (0,0) grid +(16,24);
    %\draw[->, decorate, decoration={snake}] (0,0) -- (0,16);
    %\draw[help lines] (2,0) grid +(2,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Also I have not been able to give you decorations like the snake on tikzpicture

Comment: Please remove unnecessary packages in order to get an MWE, read : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative, you can define the grid into an underlay option and clipped with a `tcbclipinterior` environment. This way, the box and grid are breakable

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[showframe=true, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced,
%   height fill,
    breakable,
    colback=white,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \draw[help lines,step=0.5cm, shift={(interior.north west)}] (interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);
        \node [signal,draw,signal to=nowhere,text=white,fill=blue!50, signal from=east, anchor=north] (signal) at (interior.north) {Write book};
\end{tcbclipinterior}}]
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 perfect, I didn't know that possibility, thank you.

Comment: oh very good tip, my question is related to creating grids without letters, and I used `\vspace {22in} \noindent` instead of  `\lipsum` but it still doesn't generate grid on the next page

Answer (score 2):

The figures produced by TikZ are not breakable. To place the signal correctly, I used `(current bounding box.north)` instead of the coordinates, which solves this problem.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}%
%\usepackage{amsfonts}%
%\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage[showframe=true, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}%
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines,step=0.5cm](0,0) grid (16,18.5);
    \node [signal,draw,signal to=nowhere,text=white,fill=blue!50, signal from=east] at (current bounding box.north) {Write book};
    %\draw[->, decorate, decoration={snake}] (0,0) -- (0,16);
    %\draw[help lines] (2,0) grid +(2,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: excelente, tank you @AndréC